# Наикошенный/наикошеный

Tags: орфография

Как правильно? Не изменять предложения и не говорить, что это бред бреддомовский!

`Этот луг, в отличие от моего недокошенного, — наикошенный/наикошеный!`

`Этот луг, в отличие от моего недокошенного, — наикошеннейший/наикошенейший!`

`Этот луг кошенее/кошеннее, чем мой.`

Comment: Приставка "наи" не употребляется с прилагательными не в превосходной степени. Нету слов наисвежий, наикрасивый, наикрутой. Но есть наисвежайший, наикрасивейший, наикрутейший.

Comment: Может быть вы имели ввиду кошернеший-наикошернейший? Кошачий луг кошернее моего некошерного?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любопытны запреты и их возможные обходы, поднятые в этом вопросе:

1. Причастия не могут иметь превосходной или сравнительной степени.
2. Прилагательные не могут иметь кучи вариативных приставок.
3. Прилагательные не в превосходной степени не могут иметь приставки "наи".

Исходя из этого правильными могут являться только 2 предложения из 6:

```
Этот луг, в отличие от моего недокошенного, — наикошенейший! 
Этот луг кошенее, чем мой.
```

Comment: Не думаю, что есть слова кошенейший, и кошенее.

Comment: Вы думаете, что русский язык - это девушка или гаишник? Так девушка или гаишник? Или гаишник девушка?

Comment: Скорее, как у котов и гаишников девушек, но этак скоро мяукать начнем, все девушки любят мяукающих няшных котиков, даже девушки гаишницы.